# Execute JavaScript function only once and remember it

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, local-storage

I have this JavaScript function which I need to be executed only once (when certain criteria are met) and then for cookies to remember it and not run it again for 24 hours.

I tried this script which uses the jquery.cookie.js plugin, but it doesn't work:

```
var eventsFired = ($.cookie('eventsFired') != null)
? $.cookie('eventsFired')
: 0;

function load() {

  if (eventsFired == 0){

    if (window.frames[0].document.getElementById('applications')) {
      var str=document.getElementById("tst").innerHTML;
      var n=str.replace("Login","Logout");
      document.getElementById("tst").innerHTML=n;
      document.getElementById('tst').title ='logout';
      document.getElementById('tst').href='logout';
      document.getElementById('prt').href='../profile/cont.html';
      eventsFired++;
      $.cookie('eventsFired', eventsFired);
    }
  }
}
```

Localstorage  :

```
function load() {
var eventsFired = localStorage.getItem('fired');

if (eventsFired == '1'){
  if (window.frames[0].document.getElementById('applications'))
{
var str=document.getElementById("tst").innerHTML;
var n=str.replace("Login","Logout");
document.getElementById("tst").innerHTML=n;
document.getElementById('common').href='..css/common2.css';
document.getElementById('tst').title ='logout';
document.getElementById('tst').href='logout';
document.getElementById('prt').href='../profil/cont.html';
  localStorage.setItem('fired', '1');
}
}
}
```

Comment: Please describe what "won't work" means.  Are there errors on your console?  What happens (if anything).  What do you expect to happen that isn't happening, etc.

Comment: I expect script to run only once and cookies to remember changes made on first execution, which is to change those elements on parent page. console : TypeError: $.cookie is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

var eventsFired = ($.cookie('eventsFired') != null)

Comment: That error message is the key and should definitely be included in your question.  It would seem as though you have not properly included the cookie library.

Comment: local storage: if(eventsFired != '1')

Comment: The cookie library is fine now, no console errors but cookies still didn't save the state after function is executed and runs on every refresh.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a cookie: it will be sent to the server at each request. You can use [local storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage#Local_and_session_storage) instead:

```
function load() {
  var eventsFired = localStorage.getItem('fired');

  if (eventsFired != '1'){
      doYourStuff();
      localStorage.setItem('fired', '1');
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated the post,I implemment it your code on my script but now will not trigger the script at all. Please check, what I did wrong ?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. Please retry.

Comment: Still not working, function does not trigger now. Maybe I didn't made myself clear: My functions changes Login in Logout, one css file with another one,etc. I need script to run once to make the changes, save that state on localstorage (with changes), than, on next refresh script will not run but people will see the changes made when script run it first time.